# Selecting max() of multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok, here's my table:

```
product_id  version_id  update_id  patch_id
  1           1           0          0
  1           1           1          0
  1           1           1          1
  1           1           2          0
  1           1           2          1
  2           1           0          0
  2           2           0          0
  2           3           0          0
  2           3           0          1
  3           1           0          0
  3           1           0          1
```

Now I want to select the latest version of a product, so the version with the highest update_id & patch_id.

For example, the latest version of

- product 1 should return 1, 2, 1
- product 2 should return 3, 0, 1
- product 3 should return 1, 0, 1

I was trying all kinds of stuff with GROUP BY and HAVING, tried subqueries, but I still can't figure out a way to accomplish this.

Can anybody help me out to find the right query, or should I think of writing a php function for this?

**Edit**

Some additional info:
- The columns together are the primary key (there are more colums, but for this problem they don't matter)
- None of the columns is auto-increment

This is the table:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db`.`patch` (
`product_id` INT NOT NULL ,
`version_id` INT NOT NULL ,
`update_id` INT NOT NULL ,
`patch_id` INT NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`, `version_id`, `update_id`, `patch_id`) ,
INDEX `fk_patch_update1` (`product_id` ASC, `version_id` ASC, `update_id` ASC) )
```

**Edit 2**

Flagged as duplicate, it is not: The other question looks for records higher than a value for any of the three different columns.

In this question we look for the highest version number grouped by the product_id.

**Edit 3**

rgz's answer tells me again that this is a duplicate. First of all: this question is older. Secondly, I don't think the answer is the same.

rgz suggests using the following query:

```
SELECT product_id, GREATEST(version_id, update_id, patch_id) AS latest_version FROM patch.
```

GREATEST(1,2,3) returns 3, right? Wat if we have these values:

```
  product_id  version_id  update_id  patch_id
  1           1           0          0
  1           1           2          8
  1           3           0          0
```

As I understand, this query wil return:

```
  product_id  latest_version
  1                 1
  1                 8
  1                 3
```

But it should return:

```
  product_id  version_id update_id  patch_id
  1           3          0          0
```

I don't think GREATEST could help. If you think it will, please prove me wrong.

Comment: I know it's an old question, but you could also do this: SELECT * FROM db.patch ORDER BY UPDATE_ID DESC, PATCH_ID DESC LIMIT 1;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql max value from 3 different columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845555/mysql-max-value-from-3-different-columns)

Comment: @rgz This is not a duplicate. See my edit.

Comment: To clarify, is the condition that the return rows must have the highest patch_id of the highest update_id of the highest version_id of each product_id?

Comment: Yes, that is the condition.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is one example of when unique identifers come in useful.

Imagine you have an autoincrememnting ID field, you can then find the id you want for each product by using a correlated sub-query...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
  id = (
        SELECT   id
        FROM     yourTable AS lookup
        WHERE    lookup.product_id = yourTable.product_id
        ORDER BY version_id DESC, update_id DESC, patch_id DESC
        LIMIT    1
       )
```

The equivalent *without* a unique identifer requires multiple correlated sub-queries...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
     version_id = (
                   SELECT   MAX(version_id)
                   FROM     yourTable AS lookup
                   WHERE    lookup.product_id = yourTable.product_id
                  )
  AND update_id = (
                   SELECT   MAX(update_id)
                   FROM     yourTable AS lookup
                   WHERE    lookup.product_id = yourTable.product_id
                     AND    lookup.version_id = yourTable.version_id
                  )
  AND patch_id  = (
                   SELECT   MAX(patch_id)
                   FROM     yourTable AS lookup
                   WHERE    lookup.product_id = yourTable.product_id
                     AND    lookup.version_id = yourTable.version_id
                     AND    lookup.update_id  = yourTable.update_id
                  )
```

This would be significantly slower than on a table with a unique identifier column.

Another alternative (without a unique identifier) is to self-join on different levels of aggregation.

```
SELECT
  yourTable.*
FROM
  (SELECT product_id, MAX(version_id) AS max_version_id FROM yourTable GROUP BY product_id) AS version
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT product_id, version_id, MAX(update_id) AS max_update_id FROM yourTable GROUP BY product_id, version_id) AS update
    ON  update.product_id = version.product_id
    AND update.version_id = version.max_version_id
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT product_id, version_id, updatE_id, MAX(patch_id) AS max_patch_id FROM yourTable GROUP BY product_id, version_id) AS patch
    ON  patch.product_id = update.product_id
    AND patch.version_id = update.version_id
    AND patch.update_id  = update.max_update_id
INNER JOIN
  yourTable
    ON  yourTable.product_id = patch.product_id
    AND yourTable.version_id = patch.version_id
    AND yourTable.update_id  = patch.update_id
    AND yourTable.patch_id   = patch.max_patch_id
```

Comment: there is a comma missing before `patch_id` btw (its not a big enough change that SO will allow me to edit)

Comment: What happens if this row is in the table (1,1,1,3) ?

Comment: @fred - With the auto incrementing ID field, each row has a unique identifier.  Then, the sub-query finds all records for the associated product_id.  Then, only the first one is chosen (highest Version, Update, Patch).  Then the outer-query picks up the records with that unique id.  In short, it still works, whatever values you have.

Comment: Forgot to tell, none of the columns is auto-increment. The primary key is product_id, version_id, update_id and patch_id together. So, in my case this won't help, will it?

Comment: @ScubaKay - Correct, you'd need to add such a column to your data.  It is an example where a unique identifier (rather than a composite key) can be very helpful.

Comment: Maybe I'll do that, first I'll take a look at some other answers.

Comment: I tried out your queries against the sample data. The 2nd and 3rd queries work great !!! +1 !!!

Comment: Well, thank you very much. I'm gonna use your example with the correlated sub-queries, works perfect!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
Select product_id, version_id, update_id, patch_id
from (select * from MyTable 
      order by product_id, version_id desc, update_id desc, patch_id desc) as v
group by product_id
```

Excuse me, it's @RolandoMySQLDBA. Forgive the intrusion, but I am posting your query and its output against the sample data:

```
mysql> Select product_id, version_id, update_id, patch_id
    -> from (select * from prod
    ->       order by product_id, version_id desc, update_id desc, patch_id desc) as v
    -> group by product_id  ;
+------------+------------+-----------+----------+
| product_id | version_id | update_id | patch_id |
+------------+------------+-----------+----------+
|          1 |          1 |         2 |        1 |
|          2 |          3 |         0 |        1 |
|          3 |          1 |         0 |        1 |
+------------+------------+-----------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Your query works as shown. It is also simpler than my answer. Good Show !!!

Comment: Does that even work in a parrallised environment where different threads could be processing different parts of the table?  And/or do you have any citations that show the ORDER is maintained and relevant to the outer query?  [the whole thing of MySQL allowing this just scares me a bit]

Comment: This seems to work, @Dems In newbie language, what's your problem with this approach?

Comment: @Dems: I thought I had read that MySQL takes the values from the first record within the group (ordered by index if no overriding sort order is specified; order by clauses with or after the group are only applied *after* the grouping), but I can't find any citation for this. By contrast, the MySQL Reference Manual, in the section relating to "GROUP BY and HAVING with Hidden Columns", explicitly says of non-grouped columns that "the result
is indeterminate".

Comment: @Scuba, Dems is concerned that this approach may not be reliable, even if it works under test conditions.

Comment: I am surprised. I tried your query against the sample data in my question AND YOUR QUERY WORKS !!! + 1 !!!

Comment: @ScubaKay - As MarkBannister said, I'm not 100% certain that the ORDERing of the data will ***guarantee*** how the results are selected.  If, for example, multiple cores are tasked to complete this, will the results still be the same?  Possibly, but that's a hard test to engineer.  And there don't *seem* to be any documents confirming it.  Most actually say you *can't* be guaranteed what the results will be.  Which is why I said it scares me a bit ;)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it but i'm sure you can do something like this

```
SELECT val.product_id, MAX(val.myVersion)
FROM (SELECT product_id, ((version_id * 10 + update_id) * 10 + patch_id) as myVersion
      FROM myTable) as val
GROUP by product_id;
```

Excuse me, it's @RolandoMySQLDBA. Forgive the intrusion, but I am posting your query and its output against the sample data:

```
mysql> SELECT val.product_id, MAX(val.myVersion)
    -> FROM (SELECT product_id, ((version_id * 10 + update_id) * 10 + patch_id) as myVersion
    ->       FROM prod) as val
    -> GROUP by product_id;
+------------+--------------------+
| product_id | MAX(val.myVersion) |
+------------+--------------------+
|          1 |                121 |
|          2 |                301 |
|          3 |                101 |
+------------+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Although display is different, your query logically works for the original question. +1 from me !!!

Answer (score 0):

You could group by `max(update_id * maxpatchidvalue + patch_id)` to get what you want.

Comment: I think update 2, patch 0 is more recent than update 1, patch 1.

Comment: assuminga max_patch_id of 100 : (2 * 100 + 0) > (1 * 100 + 1) => this mechanism works provided that it does not cause an overflow error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT
  version_id,
  max_update.update_id,
  max_patch.patch_id
FROM
  TABLE
    OUTER APPLY
    (
      SELECT TOP 1
        update_id
      FROM
        TABLE t1
      WHERE
        TABLE.version_id = t1.version_id
        AND TABLE.product_id = t1.product_id
      ORDER BY update_id DESC
    ) max_update
    OUTER APPLY
    (
      SELECT TOP 1
        patch_id 
      FROM
        TABLE t1
      WHERE
        TABLE.version_id = t1.version_id
        AND TABLE.product_id = t1.product_id
        AND max_update.update_id = t1.update_id
      ORDER BY patch_id DESC
    ) max_patch
```

Comment: You need to join on product_id as well.  ORDER BY isn;t needed when you use MAX().  Then, what if you have (2,0) and (1,1)?  Your mechanism gives (2,1) as the result, even though it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Using your input data from the question, and a table with no keys, here is a rather sick approach that works:

First of all, the query you need is this:

```
select A.* from prod A LEFT JOIN
(select product_id,max(tagnum) maxtag from
(select *,(version_id*10000+update_id*100+patch_id) tagnum from prod) AA
group by product_id) B
USING (product_id)
WHERE (version_id*10000+update_id*100+patch_id) = B.maxtag;
```

Here is some sample code using all integers, no indexes, and your sample data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS prod;
CREATE TABLE prod
(
product_id INT,
version_id INT,
update_id INT,
patch_id INT
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
INSERT INTO prod VALUES
( 1,  1,  0, 0 ),
( 1,  1,  1, 0 ),
( 1,  1,  1, 1 ),
( 1,  1,  2, 0 ),
( 1,  1,  2, 1 ),
( 2,  1,  0, 0 ),
( 2,  2,  0, 0 ),
( 2,  3,  0, 0 ),
( 2,  3,  0, 1 ),
( 3,  1,  0, 0 ),
( 3,  1,  0, 1 );
select * from prod;
select *,(version_id*10000+update_id*100+patch_id) tagnum from prod;
select A.* from prod A LEFT JOIN
(select product_id,max(tagnum) maxtag from
(select *,(version_id*10000+update_id*100+patch_id) tagnum from prod) AA
group by product_id) B
USING (product_id)
WHERE (version_id*10000+update_id*100+patch_id) = B.maxtag;
```

Here is the result:

```
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS prod;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE prod
    -> (
    -> product_id INT,
    -> version_id INT,
    -> update_id INT,
    -> patch_id INT
    -> ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO prod VALUES
    -> ( 1,  1,  0, 0 ),
    -> ( 1,  1,  1, 0 ),
    -> ( 1,  1,  1, 1 ),
    -> ( 1,  1,  2, 0 ),
    -> ( 1,  1,  2, 1 ),
    -> ( 2,  1,  0, 0 ),
    -> ( 2,  2,  0, 0 ),
    -> ( 2,  3,  0, 0 ),
    -> ( 2,  3,  0, 1 ),
    -> ( 3,  1,  0, 0 ),
    -> ( 3,  1,  0, 1 );
Query OK, 11 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 11  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from prod;
+------------+------------+-----------+----------+
| product_id | version_id | update_id | patch_id |
+------------+------------+-----------+----------+
|          1 |          1 |         0 |        0 |
|          1 |          1 |         1 |        0 |
|          1 |          1 |         1 |        1 |
|          1 |          1 |         2 |        0 |
|          1 |          1 |         2 |        1 |
|          2 |          1 |         0 |        0 |
|          2 |          2 |         0 |        0 |
|          2 |          3 |         0 |        0 |
|          2 |          3 |         0 |        1 |
|          3 |          1 |         0 |        0 |
|          3 |          1 |         0 |        1 |
+------------+------------+-----------+----------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select *,(version_id*10000+update_id*100+patch_id) tagnum from prod;
+------------+------------+-----------+----------+--------+
| product_id | version_id | update_id | patch_id | tagnum |
+------------+------------+-----------+----------+--------+
|          1 |          1 |         0 |        0 |  10000 |
|          1 |          1 |         1 |        0 |  10100 |
|          1 |          1 |         1 |        1 |  10101 |
|          1 |          1 |         2 |        0 |  10200 |
|          1 |          1 |         2 |        1 |  10201 |
|          2 |          1 |         0 |        0 |  10000 |
|          2 |          2 |         0 |        0 |  20000 |
|          2 |          3 |         0 |        0 |  30000 |
|          2 |          3 |         0 |        1 |  30001 |
|          3 |          1 |         0 |        0 |  10000 |
|          3 |          1 |         0 |        1 |  10001 |
+------------+------------+-----------+----------+--------+
11 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select A.* from prod A LEFT JOIN
    -> (select product_id,max(tagnum) maxtag from
    -> (select *,(version_id*10000+update_id*100+patch_id) tagnum from prod) AA
    -> group by product_id) B
    -> USING (product_id)
    -> WHERE (version_id*10000+update_id*100+patch_id) = B.maxtag;
+------------+------------+-----------+----------+
| product_id | version_id | update_id | patch_id |
+------------+------------+-----------+----------+
|          1 |          1 |         2 |        1 |
|          2 |          3 |         0 |        1 |
|          3 |          1 |         0 |        1 |
+------------+------------+-----------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Give it a Try !!!

CAVEAT

My answer will support per product

- up to 99 versions
- up to 99 updates
- up to 99 patches

Comment: Formula is different. I use `version_id*10000+update_id*100+patch_id`. @fge uses `update_id * maxpatchidvalue + patch_id`

Comment: My answer produces the desired output based on the input data supplied in the question.

Answer (score -1):

MySQL has the `GREATEST` function so you should use it like this:

```
SELECT product_id, GREATEST(version_id, update_id, patch_id) AS latest_version FROM patch.
```

I marked this question as a duplicate because both questions are basically asking the same thing, selecting the maximum value of several columns. Here you use it in the SELECT clause, in the other question you use it in the WHERE clause. In either case GREATEST does the trick.

Comment: You marked this question as a duplicate of a question a year younger by the way.

Comment: GREATEST(1,2,3) returns 3, right? Wat if we have these values:

      product_id  version_id  update_id  patch_id
        1           1           0          0
        1           1           2          8
        1           3           0          0

As I understand, your query wil return:

      product_id  latest_version
      1                 1
      1                 8
      1                 3

But it should return:

      product_id  version_id update_id  patch_id
      1                 3               0                0

Comment: > You marked this question as a duplicate of a question a year younger by the way < 
I did? So what? I'm just trying to reduce the number of redundant questions i wasn't thinking of seniority.