# Mysql max value from 3 different columns

Tags: mysql, sql, max

Is there any way to find maximum value of 3 different columns? I'm trying to find records with any of 3 columns value higher than specified value and trying to avoid making something like this in query:

```
column1 > 69 or column2 > 69 or column3 > 69
```

Table structure is like this:

```
id | column1 | column2 | column3
1  |   5     |    4    |    3
2  |  70     |    1    |    65
3  |  66     |    3    |    90
```

And select like this:

```
select id from tablex where column1 > 69 or column2 > 69 or column3 > 69

-- but with better query, a bit prettier like this (it doesn't work of course)

select id from tablex where MAX(column1, column2, column3) > 69
```

Comment: *RE: trying to avoid making something like this* Why? It is not extremely long or cryptic. While one liners are nice, if they both yield the same result, performance is more important. You may want examine the query plans before you pick an approach. If they are the same (I do not know whether they are or not..) pick the one you prefer. Otherwise, I would go with the more efficient syntax.

Comment: Yup but still this is simple one time script which will be used from time to time. More important is logic structure and readability than performance itself ;)

Comment: Ah, okay. I did not realize it was a one-off. In that case I agree performance is less critical. If you do get a chance to look at the query plans, let us know ;-) I would be curious if there is any difference.

Comment: @Leigh, the `OR` query is far more likely to use indexes.

Comment: @ypercube - Ah, okay thanks. I guess I am not surprised, since applying functions to a filter column will usually prevent the db from using indexes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you need to use [GREATEST](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/greatest-function.php)

like that

```
    select id from tablex where GREATEST(column1, column2, column3) > 69
```

Comment: True... I came to this answer like in same time :) Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I want to point out that:

```
where GREATEST(column1, column2, column3) > 69;
```

is *not* the same as:

```
where column1 > 69 or column2 > 69 or column3 > 69;
```

The first will filter out all rows where any of the three columns is `NULL`.  The second will still consider these rows.  You could rewrite the `GREATEST()` query as:

```
where GREATEST(coalesce(column1, 0), coalesce(column2, 0), coalesce(column3, 0)) > 69;
```

but that defeats the purpose of the simpler syntax.  You may *know* that the column values are never `NULL`, in which case using `greatest()` is ok.  But, it is not a general substitute.

Comment: Good spot. I had not realized `greatest` included nulls. (Makes complete sense though.)