# Selecting column with highest value in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, multiple-columns

I have a table that is something like below

```
column1 | column2 | column3 | column4
   43        12        1        132
```

Obviously, the 'column4' has the highest value. So my goal is to retrieve this column.

Desire results:

```
   column4
     132
```

Comment: You completely don't know what you are doing, am I right?

Comment: Aksed and answered previously: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845555/mysql-max-value-from-3-different-columns use GREATEST. fiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e850/1/0

Comment: That's true, but how would I keep the name of the column? Your reference only tells you to get the value with the highest column.

Comment: @user3135626 . . . Can the columns have `NULL` values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the column name:

```
select greatest(column1, column2, column3, column4) as biggestval,
       (case when column1 = greatest(column1, column2, column3, column4)  then 'column1'
             when column2 = greatest(column1, column2, column3, column4)  then 'column2'
             when column3 = greatest(column1, column2, column3, column4)  then 'column3'
             when column4 = greatest(column1, column2, column3, column4)  then 'column4'
        end) as biggestval_columnname
```

Note that this will not work if any of the columns have `NULL` values.

Comment: Cool! But how would I keep the name of the column? Such as column4: 132?

Comment: @user3135626 . . . This has two columns, one with the value and one with the column name.

Answer (score 6):

Try the function [GREATEST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest):

```
SELECT GREATEST(column1, column2 colum3, column4)
FROM table
```

Comment: This is good solution, but how would I keep the name of the column?

Comment: You can't using greatest and only have 1 column returned.  A column couldn't have two names say greatest for row 1 is column 1 but column 4 for row 2.  It can't be both, thus you must alias the column or get a system assigned name.

Comment: Then why suggest the GREATEST() function? I clearly stated above, that I wanted to get the value and keep the name of the column.

Comment: One shouldn't "look the gift horse in the mouth", as it were. @user3135626 - Your comment sounds like you ordered Steak at a restaurant, and got Corned Beef instead.

Comment: Sorry, I was reading "want to retrieve this value" in your question. If you need the column name and value for the highest value for each row you should go with the answer of Gordon or parse the result in php. There is no need to be aggressive on SO just because your definition of "clearly stated" differs from mine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT
   CASE
       WHEN column1 >= column2 AND column1 >= column3 THEN column1
       WHEN column2 >= column1 AND column2 >= column3 THEN column2
       WHEN column3 >= column1 AND Date3 >= column2 THEN column3
       ELSE  column1 
   END AS TopColumn
```

There isn't a SQL standard function that makes what you have requested

Comment: Is that from this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022/sql-max-of-multiple-columns

Comment: Yes! This is the logic solution from your post

Answer (score 0):

Stock your value in a array and use function PHP MAX , Try this

```
$sql = 'SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4 FROM table';
$req = mysql_query($sql) or die('Erreur SQL !<br>'.$sql.'<br>'.mysql_error());
$t_number=array();
$i=0;
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($req)){
  $t_number[$i]=array(
        $data['column1'],
        $data['column2'],
        $data['column3'],
        $data['column4']
 );
   $maxValue=max($t_number[$i]);
   echo $maxValue;
   $i++;
}
```

Comment: This looks promising, however, in the future, please use `mysqli_*` instead of `mysql_*` based functions. Some may downvote this because of that, yet not me; it's not my style ;-)